# How to Create layout(see attached image) in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have been facing problem to create below layout. How can i do it. Should i use CustomView or use image?
If i use CustomeView than how can i do it? 
Please suggest any customView reference or idea to achieve that layout.
I have tried to use Path in onDraw method in customView than i really did not know what to do and i was stuck.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can use Card Layout and Make use of images and button e.g View and make its event.

Comment: Use FrameLayout ..

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add card view dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
```

**2.** Take below xml and put it where you are bridging it. Let's say you use `RecyclerView` with `CardView`: for above layout use two `ImageViews` and a `Button` or whatever you want. Design images and check the layout. You should be able to achieve what you want 
e.g

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
app:cardElevation="1dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/icons"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_small">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_tiny"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="TITLE OF THE POST"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_regular"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:typeface="roboto_bold"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@color/icons"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postTitle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```